# problems with transfer learning: using my own trained weights, or the Usiigaci trained wieghts for MRCNN (matterport implementation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, transfer-learning

my project involves cell detection, so I thought I'd try training my NN using [Usiigaci pre-trained weights](https://github.com/oist/Usiigaci).
but when I try I get the following error:
`ValueError: Layer #362 (named "anchors") expects 1 weight(s), but the saved weights have 0 element(s)`.
The training works fine for pretrained coco weigths for example.
this is the code i use to load the weights:

```
model = MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config) model.load_weights('Usiigaci_3.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
```

I also get a similar problem when trying to load the weights that were generated by training my model over my own photos, to continue the training where I stopped the last time.
the error received is:

```
ValueError: Layer #362 (named "anchors"), weight <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(4, 261888, 4) dtype=float32> has shape (4, 261888, 4), but the saved weight has shape (2, 261888, 4).
```

loading the weights:

```
model.load_weights('new_weigths/40_epochs/mask_rcnn_cell_cfg_0040.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
```

please let me know if you understand why is this happening.
thanks!!